# Consumer-producer pattern with wait/notify pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I'm working on a producer-consumer pattern that should work with a queue. As usually a consumer `Thread` and a `Producer` thread, producer will add an item to the queue **at certain times interval (from 3 to 5 seconds)**, consumer will wait to process it as soon as the queue isn't empty.

As a requirement the **producer** should and will produce items non-stop, which means if the queue is full, it will keep producing, and that's why I can't use `BlockingQueue` implementations as they either wait for the queue to have available space or throw exception.

My current implementation is the following

```
// consumer's Runnable
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        if(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            currentItem = queue.poll();
            process(currentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

This thread will keep looping even if no item has been produced by the producer `Thread`.

How is it done to wait until the producer add an item to the queue, and also what is a good `Queue` implementation with no cap-limit ?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc? What don't you understand?

Comment: Yes I have read it, and also several posts. It's hard to explain what I don't understand, since I'm new to wait/notify and also to BlockingQueue. That's what I want a simple example about producing at a time interval and consuming as soon as it is available

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to ask for examples. Use google to find one and if there's something you don't understand, and the documentation doesn't explain, come back and ask about it.

Comment: There you go, updated the question

Comment: Your consumer implementation does unnecessary looping (busy waiting). Just use `take()`. It will wait until an item becomes available.